# Why does Go's LookupAddr end in period?

Tags: python, go

I am doing a reverse ip lookup using Go:

```
hosts, err := net.LookupAddr("google.com")
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println(err)
}
fmt.Println(hosts)
```

Results:

```
[den02s02-in-f14.1e100.net.]
```

The same in Python:

```
addr1 = socket.gethostbyaddr('google.com')
print(addr1)
```

results:

```
('den02s02-in-f14.1e100.net', [], ['172.217.12.14'])
```

Why does the Go version end in period?

Comment: That's not anything particular to Go, it's a [Fully Qualified Domain Name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fully_qualified_domain_name)

Comment: The Go output is correct. This is how DNS works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is how a correct fully qualified domain name is *supposed to be* formatted. It tells anything reading that hostname that it is fully qualified and not partially qualified. Failure to output such FQDNs is common, and not necessarily a problem for most software. Until it is, of course.

Refs: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fully_qualified_domain_name), et al.

Comment: The Python version is not strictly correct, no. I'm sure there is a flamewar on some bug report page somewhere that would call me all sorts of terrible names for saying so.

Comment: Correct or incorrect depends on context. Python's `socket.gethostbyaddr` isn't supposed to return a fully-qualified domain name. There's `socket.getfqdn` for that.

Comment: ...wait, no, `socket.getfqdn` doesn't add the trailing `.` either.

Comment: You know, I almost added "it depends on the context" but what the hell. I love to take a dig at Python any chance I can get. That being said, socket IO in most langs doesn't care. This might be a case of adhering to a specification almost to spite it. (PostFix, I'm looking in your direction.)

Comment: Python's answer isn't "incorrect", it's just not a FQDN, which means that using the result requires extra validation steps.  So, in a pragmatic sense, Python's answer is "less efficient."

Comment: @Flimzy one could make the argument that `socket.getfqdn()` is incorrect, though. In general, one only cares if one is actually doing strict lookups and you want to know if you need to add domain parts. Which in my experience is rare.

Comment: You know, given that GoLang is intended to be a Rust-like safe and fast concurrent systems programming language (that has the main benefit of not being C++) it makes total sense that a FQDN would be strict.